# Delete records from Mysql based on txt

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple txt file with email addresses. I want to check if these addresses are in my database and if so: delete them.

The txt file is not in a csv format, but every email addresses is on a new line. I'm wondering whats the best way to do this.

Comment: Here a little tutorial on how to break each line into an array: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php10p7.html

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

This regular expression will match a new line
`([^\n]*\n+)+`

Add a comma after every line (or replace the NEWLINE with comma) so the list will become from 
`email1@com.com
email2@com.com
email3@com.com`

to `email@com.com,email2@com.com,email3@com.com`

Add brackets to the beggining and end:
`(email@com.com,email2@com.com,email3@com.com)`

Add the following sql:

`DELETE FROM database.schema.table WHERE email_address IN (email@com.com,email2@com.com,email3@com.com);`

Execute the `SQL`.

You can execute the query from php or directly in the database, keep backups please else you might screw up smth...
Hope this helps...
Good Luck

Comment: @fortune - your foreach will execute as many db statements as the length of the email list which is not recommended if the list is very long (maybe 50 000 emails) in contrary, in a short list then its fine.

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is [fgets()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).

```
<?php
$emails = array();

if( ! $fh = fopen('file.txt', 'r') ) { die('could not open file'); }
while( $buffer = fgets($fh, 4096) ) {
    $emails[] = $buffer;
}
fclose($fh);

foreach($emails as $email) {
    $query = sprintf("DELETE FROM table WHERE email LIKE '%s'", $email);
    // do the query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = file("emails.txt");
foreach ($file as $email) {

      $query = sprintf("DELETE FROM table WHERE email LIKE '%s'", $email);
      # execute query
}  

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Read the emails in one at a time and then run the delete query with the value. DO NOT USE `mysql_query` (unless you trust the input from text file, but even then just use the newer libraries please). If the records are there, they will be deleted, if not no biggie nothing happens. Done.